# Using Multiple Sources in SSIS Data Flow Task

Tags: sql, ssis, dataflowtask

For my data flow task I have a OLEDB Source. In the SQL command section of this I have  compiled a select query based on tables from two different databases, held on the same instance. Every time I run this it errors, but when I moved the tables to the same database (for testing purposes) it worked.

I'm guessing from this that the source data needs to be from the same database but is there anyway around this? I tried using a look-up but I couldn't get it to work. I could create a view in the source database but I'm guessing there must be a way to keep it all within the package.

Thank you in advance! This is the query I was using in the OLE DB Source:

select *
    from commoncomponents.meta.ItemTypeLabelDefinition 
    where internalid not in 
        (
            select internalid
                from iscanimport.dbo.ItemTypeLabelDefinition 
            )

Comment: " it errors" - suggest you post the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the cross-DB query wouldn't work in the one source, but one method would be to create two OleDb Sources, one pointing to CommonComponents DB doing the select from ItemTypeLabelDefinition, and the other pointing to IScanImport and the select statement from your sub-query.  Preferably sort these the same way at source in your queries, then use a Merge Join task to combine them.

Comment: Aaah very clever, thank you! I will give that a go! Thank you for the really quick response too I really appreciate it!

Comment: This seemed to work but when it came to inserting the data into the destination location I get the following message:[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "SQL Server Destination" (16) failed with error code 0xC02092B5 while processing input "SQL Server Destination Input" (32). I read this could be because null values are illegal in the destination source but this is not the case and I have checked the data in a data viewer and looks fine. Do you have any ideas please? This is driving me CRAZY! Thanks!